# json object containing array maps to asp.net dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I know the question title is not very clear and specific but I really have no idea how to describe it in a few words. Here comes a little more story about it.

I wanna send an object by POST request to ASP.NET 4 MVC controller, and hopefully it will bind to a C# model. Front end is angular 1.5 and the object is not sent via form submit.

What I want to send

```
var model = {    
    id:1,
    filters: {
      filterBy: ["date"],
      warehouseId: [101, 102, 103],
      orderStatus: ["completed", "placed"],
      currencyId: [140, 209]
    }
}
```

The C# model looks

```
public class FilterModel{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller function looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Export(FilterModel model){
    //....
}
```

Through debugging I can see that when JS object value's array has ony one element, I can successfully get a Dictionary structure with 4 records which are the 4 filters' key and value pairs.

```
//Seudo code
{Key:"filterBy", Value: "date"}
{Key:"warehouseId", Value: "101"}
{Key:"orderStatus", Value: "completed"}
{Key:"currencyId", Value: "140"}
```

And I can get the value by:

```
var warehouseId = model.Filters["warehouseId"][0] // 101
var orderStatus = model.Filters["orderStatus"][0] // completed
```

However, when the JS object's array has multiple values, the weird part comes. Instead of 4 records, I will get 8 records, which look like:

```
//Seudo code
{Key:"filterBy", Value: "date"}
{Key:"warehouseId[0]", Value: "101"}
{Key:"warehouseId[1]", Value: "102"}
{Key:"warehouseId[2]", Value: "103"}
{Key:"orderStatus[0]", Value: "completed"}
{Key:"orderStatus[1]", Value: "placed"}
{Key:"currencyId[0]", Value: "140"}
{Key:"currencyId[1]", Value: "209"}
```

(Please tell me if the description isn't clear enough)

I wonder why this happened and how to fix it? I have changed to use another model for each single filter key value pair, but still curious about the reason of this problem.

Appreciate your wisdom!

Comment: If you want to send it in the format in your first snippet, then `Filters` should be an object containing 4 properties that are collections - e.g. `string[] filterBy`, `int[] warehouseId` etc

Answer (score 1):

I think your model is wrong. Try this:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("filters")]
    public Filters Filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filters
{
    [JsonProperty("filterBy")]
    public string[] FilterBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("warehouseId")]
    public long[] WarehouseId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("orderStatus")]
    public string[] OrderStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currencyId")]
    public long[] CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have figured out using ViewModel like you wrote, but I want to know why that model binding is failed, seeing that C# model is Dictionary<string, string[ ]>, I thought each filter key-value pair can be mapped to a dictionary record because the dictionary value type is string[ ] too. Do you have idea about it?

Comment: I cant believe that I stuck because of using the fields instead of properties. Thank you.